# Qmake get the target output file path

Tags: qmake

I have a qmake project that looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += dll
TARGET = mydll

SOURCES += ...
HEADERS += ....
```

Now I want to add an `INSTALLS` section, so I have:

```
target.path = /path/to/somedir/
target.files =./$$TARGET

INSTALLS+= target
```

Unfortunately this will not work, because `$$TARGET` contains the target name, and not the output file name. Is there a **portable** way to obtain the output file name? (Please no platform dependent string concatenation like `lib` + `$$TARGET` + `.so`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify `target.files`, `target` is a special case and it's predefined in `qmake`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs

> If you append a built-in install set to the `INSTALLS` variable and do not specify files or extra members, `qmake` will decide what needs to be copied for you. Currently, the only supported built-in install set is `target`:
>
> ```
> target.path = /usr/local/myprogram
> INSTALLS += target
> ```
>
> In the above lines, qmake knows what needs to be copied, and will handle the installation process automatically.

Comment: Note that in Qt5 the dlltarget was added to the special targets. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files